# Using pivot_wider, but get multiple rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot

I hope someone can help me.
I have a set of vegetation data from several subplots and I need to do a Kmean Cluster analysis for my MCs project, so I hope someone can help me out since I am no way near a R-shark!

My df look something like this:

```
| Number_ID |    ID    | species_name |    PP_abundance    | 
| --------  | -------- | Alchemilla   |         0          |
|    1      |    A_1   | Antennaria   |         0          |
|    2      |    A_1   | Arabis       |         0          |
|    3      |    A_1   | Bartsia      |         0          |
|    4      |    A_1   | Betula       |         0          |
|    5      |    A_1   | Bistorta     |         0          |
|    6      |    A_1   | Carex        |         0          |
ect.         ect.       ect.           ect.
```

I then use the following code:

```
df_wide <- df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = species_name, values_from = PP_abundance)
```

And I change it to the following:

```
| Number_ID |    ID    | Alchemilla   |    Antennaria      | Arabis  | Bartsia  | ECT. 
| --------  | -------- | --------     | -------------      | -----   | -----    | ECT. 
|    1      |    A_1   |     0        |         NA         |    NA   |   NA     | ECT.
|    2      |    A_1   |     NA       |         1          |    NA   |   NA     | ECT.
|    3      |    A_1   |     NA       |         NA         |    0    |   NA     | ECT.
|    4      |    A_1   |     NA       |         NA         |    NA   |   2      | ECT.
|    5      |    A_1   |     NA       |         NA         |    NA   |   NA     | ECT.
|    6      |    A_1   |     NA       |         NA         |    NA   |   NA     | ECT.
```

More information, the ID's are subplots. They were on a grid with going from A-M and 1-15 (have have over 70 columns of specie names).
So at the moment I have several thousand rows of data, but the majority are duplicates, where there is only one piece of abundance data in one of the species columns.
My question is this, how do I merge/group the rows so that I only have one row of A1, B3, C14, D7 ect., but still retain the species columns and a sum of the abundance data?

So it looks like something like:

```
| Number_ID |    ID    | Alchemilla   |    Antennaria      | Arabis  | Bartsia  | ECT. 
| --------  | -------- | --------     | -------------      | -----   | -----    | ECT. 
|    1      |    A_1   |     0        |         1          |    0    |   2      | ECT.
|    2      |    A_2   |     3        |         0          |    1    |   0      | ECT.
|    3      |    A_3   |     0        |         3          |    0    |   1      | ECT.
|    4      |    A_4   |     2        |         4          |    0    |   2      | ECT.
|    5      |    A_5   |     0        |         2          |    1    |   0      | ECT.
|    6      |    A_6   |     0        |         0          |    0    |   1      | ECT.
```

Anyone have an idea of how to write in so that the rows are unique?

(And if anyone know how to proceed with the Kmean code that would also be much appreciated! I used

```
#Compute k-means with k = 8
set.seed(123)
km.res <- kmeans(df_wide, 8, nstart = 25)
```

But I can't do this while there is NA in my df.)

/Cheers
Birk

I've tried several different lines of code, like:

```
df_merged <- df_wide %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize_all(funs(sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

But that only gives me a df with one column with the merged subplot data, but it throws away the species names and abundace data

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! It would help if you would share a small set of sample data that illustrates the problem.  What you've shared gives a good sense of what your data is *like*, but (unless I'm misunderstanding greatly) the desired output you show with 6 different `ID` values doesn't correspond to the sample input you show, with only 1 unique `ID` value. In fact, the sample input you show has all 0 values for `PP_abundance`!

Comment: Could you find a different subset of data that better illustrates your problem? Maybe just 2 species and 3 `ID` values, and some non-0 abundance values? (I can't really tell if different `Number_ID` values are relevant or not...) And then show the desired output corresponding to that sample input, so we test answers and know whether they work or not.

Comment: The easiest and friendliest way to share sample data is often with `dput()`. If you run `dput(your_sample_data)`, it will show copy/pasteable R code to re-create `your_sample_data` including all class and structure information. It makes it very easy to work on a problem when the data is shared with `dput()`.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response @GregorThomas and thanks for a warm welcome!
I can certainly try. I have created dputs for both the df and the df_wide, but they are still over 7000 characters large, so I'll fiddle abit with it and post it asap!
But yes, I see what you mean. There are some rows that have other numbers than 0. But 0 is still a value to me, since the data is from a pinpoint method regarding vegetation analysis, where 0 indicates that species were "hit".
The different Number_ID is just a running ID my supervisor asked me to have

Comment: Remember, it doesn't necessarily need to be "real" data to illustrate the problem. Just an example of the correct structure that is demonstrates it. 5-10 rows and 3 or 4 columns should be plenty for the input, and that should correspond to a fairly small output. And don't bother with `dput()` for the output - we don't need to run code on the output just a table like you've already included would be fine.

Comment: Also, if your `species_name` or other columns are `factor` class, all possible values will be contained in the `dput()` class definition, which can make the `dput` result too long. You can avoid this with `dput(droplevels(your_sample_data))`

Comment: remove the number_ID and it will work.

Comment: (EDITED/REMOVED, Got the answer from Onyambu :) )

Comment: I will try that @Onyambu !

Comment: That actually worked @Onyambu! Thanks alot!

Comment: Should work. The num_id is just rownames. and it prevents the data being widened/casted

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question (if someone new misses the comments).
As @Onyambu points out, the "Number_Id" column have unique id's, making the rows unique, no matter that the "ID" is shared amongst the other rows. Aka, the "Number_ID" is preventing the widning of the pivot tabel.

Removing the "Number_ID" column worked, and my data are now in a widend format with the subplots as unique rows, looking like the wanted example I posted (But without the "Number_id" column)